# AngularJS parse JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I just started with learning Angular and now i'm busy with an web application that shows some records i fetched from a JSON. The JSON looks like:

```
"results": [
    {
    "easy": false,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title",
    }
]
```

i am parsing that on this way (seems correct to me)

```
var app = angular.module("DB", []);

app.controller("Controller", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
    $http.get('api_url').

    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.thing = data.results;
    });
});
```

So now that i am in this JSON file i need to get the ID (in this case its 1) and with that ID i need to do a new request `api.com/game/{id}` to get more detailed information about the result from the first file.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: You should user a factory or a service to make your API calls then inject factory or service into your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$http.get('api.com/game/' + $scope.thing.id, function(...){ });
```

Point to note, you do not have to manually parse JSON with angular. It will do that for you. So `data.results` already has the object representing your response.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is good idea if you do like this:

```
var app = angular.module("DB", []);

        app.controller("Controller", function($scope, $http) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
            $http.get('api_url').

            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.thing = data.results;
              $scope.id=data.results[0].id;
              gameInfo();
            });
        });

    var gameInfo=function(){
    $http.get('api.com/game/'+$scope.id).

            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.newThing = data;
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at ngResource which is a module that gives you more fine-grained control over HTTP requests.  It does parameter replacement among other things (custom interceptors, etc.)

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource